# Tensorflow requirements

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to deploy tensorflow on a production server. I expect about 200 concurrent users. I will be using the parser and a few of my own neural network deep learning models. I would like to know the peak memory and cpu usage for the same.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: The requirements for TensorFlow are almost entirely determined by the particular model(s) that you are running. Without details of these models, it's impossible to guess the requirements.

Answer (score 4):

Trying a simple (But very variable) guess:

If you talk about deep learning, I infer you are talking at least of 3 or more layers, including some CNN and probably RNNs.

If you are using simple 2D or 3D inputs, but a complex architecture it can be safely said that your bottleneck will be on CPU, and thus implementing the algorithms on GPU will be needed.

You also need to prepare to scale for any number of clients, so a scaling mechanism will be useful from the start.

Also you need to know how the workload will be handled, will you have to serve real time, or a batch queue is needed? This change the requirements enormously.

Once you can figure out this and maybe other details, you can refine your estimation.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

For the memory it depends on 3 factors:

- graph size
- batch size for the graph
- the queue size with the incoming request

Among the 3 factors probably the batch size has the most impact as memory of the graph is: graph size x batch size

About the CPU I suggest you to use the GPU for the graph. You can make some tests and count the number of inferences per second you can do with your graph and the selected batch size. Tensorflow serving well implemented handles concurrency very nicely and you bound is going to be the graph speed